# How many combinations can you get from a three times three matrix

Tags: matrices, permutations, combinations

I have a 3*3 matrix like this (figure 1):

```
* * *
* * *
* * *
```

Slots can be filled similar to next examples (figure 2):

```
* *    *   *    * *  * * *  * * *  * * *
* * *  * * *  * * *  * *    *   *    * *
* * *  * * *  * * *  * * *  * * *  * * * ...
```

But not only by moving one asterix but moving 1, 2,3,4,5,6 and 7 asterixes.

I have manually counted these combinations:

```
1 -> 9 (meaning with 1 asterix you get 9 combinations)
9 -> 1 (the first figure, meaning with 9 asterixes you get 1 combination)
8 -> 9 (the second figure, meaning with 8 asterixes you get 9 combinations)
2 -> 36 (with two asterixes you get 36 combinations?)
3 -> ?
4 -> ?
5 -> ?
6 -> ?
7 -> ?
------
sum: x
```

How do you get the number of all combinations you can make with from a single to 9 asterixes? I'd like to see the result and the math formula for this.

Comment: Can you add more information on what you want ?

Comment: I will add sample matrices because its harder to explain with words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n(k)$ be the number of configurations you can build with $k$ stars. If you label each star then you can ask your question differently :  How many subsets of $k$ elements can I construct from a set containing $9$ elements ? 
By definition $n(k)$ is :
$$n(k) = \left(\begin{matrix} 9\\k\end{matrix}\right) = \dfrac{9!}{k! (9-k)!}.$$
Now if you want to get the number of all the configurations you can build from a single to 9 stars, you have to compute $\sum_{k=1}^9 n(k)$ :
$$\sum_{k=1}^9 n(k) = \sum_{k=1}^9\left(\begin{matrix} 9\\k\end{matrix}\right) = 2^9 - 1=511$$

Comment: So is the answer 511 or 512? I will count the figure 1 also to the final sum...

Comment: Ok, I found it from the other answer. Depends if I include empty slot or not.

Comment: In your question you did not include empty slot.

Answer (score 2):

You said it: It is combination therefore number of options for $k$ asterix in $n= 3 \times 3$ matrix is $$ {n \choose k} = \frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}.$$

Total number of options is given by
$$ {9 \choose 0} + {9 \choose 1} +{9 \choose 2} + ... +{9 \choose 9} = 2^9.$$

Edit: In my solution is option without asterixs (empty matrix).

Comment: ...which equals $2^9$.

Comment: Good addition, empty slot would count as well as full slot, although I didn't specify it on question. I'll give this answer a thumbs up and accept the other because of sigma notation, that gives me more tools to play with the equation in [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=summation&a=*C.summation-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=9!%2F(k!(9-k)!)&f=Sum.sumfunction%5Cu005f9!%2F(k!(9-k)!)&f3=k&f=Sum.sumvariable%5Cu005fk&f4=0&f=Sum.sumlowerlimit_0&f5=9&f=Sum.sumupperlimit2%5Cu005f9) manner.